# Is there a text-replacing package for LaTeX?

Tags: packages

It's function is using the wanted text to replace specified text in `.tex` file.

Comment: Do you mean something like "Find and Replace"?

Comment: @John Wickerson Yes. It can handle a multi-replace mission between \begin{document} and \end{document}.

Comment: There're indeed such packages for strings. e.g. `xstring`. But I think you should use a text editor to do such things.

Comment: To do complex simultaneous find-and-replace operations, I would recommend a text editor like Emacs. It allows you to use [regular expressions to describe the replacement task](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Replace.html). There's quite a learning curve, but it's ultimately very powerful once learnt.

Comment: @cowkileg Is your goal to produce a new `.tex` file with some replacements performed, or is it to do some replacements on the fly, on, say, the argument to a macro you define?  In the first case you are probably better off using an external tool, in the second, packages like `xparse` or `l3regex` can be of use.  We need to have a better idea of what exactly you want to achieve and (if relevant) why you don't simply write the TeX file with the replacements (perhaps performed externally).